# What is the alternative of geometry.viewport in angular google maps API?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I am using the Google Maps Search box API and using the returned object to the set a marker on the map and set the zoom level and bounds acccordingly.

```
var location = searchBox.getPlaces();
$scope.map.control.getGMap().fitBounds(location[0].geometry.viewport);
```

My HTML markup is :

```
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options" control="map.control">
        <ui-gmap-search-box template="searchbox.template" parentdiv="'map-search-div'" events="searchbox.events"></ui-gmap-search-box>
        <ui-gmap-markers models="randomMarkers" coords="'coordinates'"  doRebuildAll="true">
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Now, when I enter the location names like city, localities and sublocalities etc. I am able to access the `geometry.viewport` object of those locations and set the map bounds. But, when enter names of premises like Buildings, Schools,etc, the `geometry` object only contains the `geometry.location` parameter and no `geometry.viewport` parameter. So, how do I appropriately set the `zoom` levels and `bounds` for the premises type locations?